# My Pixelart Look Really Pixelated In Unity

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, optimization, pixel

I don't know what it is, but my pixelart looks really pixelated and wierdly optimized. I've turned off compression and filters, but still, something isn't right. Any help would be appreciated! btw this problem only occurs on rotated sprites.

(would also enjoy some general tips on making pixel art games in unity since I am quite new.)
[image]

Comment: There is not enough context. Please show your import settings for the sprite and your scene setup.

Comment: I don't understand at all, but note you generally have to select POINT FILTER rather than eg. bilinear

Comment: That's what i meant, switched to point filter, no compression and I've installed pixel perfect, but that makes everything even wierder, almost lower resolution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As to answer your inquiry to general tips about making pixel art games in unity engine, check these out:

[A post on Unity's blog](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2019/03/13/2d-pixel-perfect-how-to-set-up-your-unity-project-for-retro-8-bits-games/) about best practices of developing pixel art games with Unity

[2D pixel perfect](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.2d.pixel-perfect@3.0/manual/index.html) is a Unity package available at your disposal "which ensures your pixel art remains crisp and clear at different resolutions, and stable in motion".